# Have a button for each php output retrieved from the Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have php code written to search for a inputted address within a mysql database.

It then returns all the addresses available in that location. This is working fine and is demonstrated by my code below. However, I want to add a button to each output value so when it is clicked on it will give all the information about that single location stored in the database. (related to that session).

Then the user is able to choose that location to travel to or go back to read more details about another location.

I am really struggling to inset that button however and have tried several different ways but nothing works. Any help would be much appreciated

```
 //collect
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE address LIKE '%$searchq%' or address2 LIKE '%$searchq%' or county LIKE '%$searchq%'") OR die("could not search!!!!");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0) {
        $output = '<h3 style="color: red">Sorry, there are no available parking options at this location. <br> Please broaden your search! </h3>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $address = $row['address']; 
            $address2 = $row['address2'];
            $county = $row['county'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $id= $row['id'];

            $output.= '<div> -----> '.$address.' '.$address2.' '.$county.' //should be a button here ---> ('.$description.')</div>';
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you say that your code works, then it's obviously not the same code you've posted here. Please copy/paste your actual code.

Comment: Sorry I had been messing with the code before posting however the code above does run perfectly for me, it is just the issue of adding a button with the session of the output I am having trouble with. Note: I have re-edited it to what works

Comment: Just create a link and pass the ID as a parameter in the query string: `<a href="info.php?id=<?= $id ?>">More info</a>`. Then on `info.php`, get the ID with something like: `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for your reply. Sorry this may be a very basic question but where do I insert the <a href="info.php?id=<?= $id ?>">More info</a> as I can't just insert it into my output line? Like I need a button to be displayed after each output so the user can pick which location suits them best

Comment: You can add it to the `$output`-string where you want it. Something like: `$output .= '<div>your current stuff <a href="info.php?id=' . $id . '">More info</a></div>'`.